# What a good regex expression to create a domain name from a string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am building a suggested subdomain name by combining the name and address.  This will result in some invalid characters.  Is there a way with regex to strip out the unwanted chars.

i.e.
tony's auto shop 123 main st. => tonys-auto-shop-123-main-st

Comment: What is your pattern exactly? Delete all invalid characters and replace white spaces with `-`? Do you have a list of all invalid characters? And what have you tried to solve your problem? And you know, regex is for search pattern/matching or something.. It does not replace or delete things.

Answer (score 0):

you could use just URL encode (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) and i think it will give you a valid domain name. However you have to decide for  yourself if you want to allow special characters like - . %20 or non-english characters.

you probally want something like

```
Regex.Replace(input, "\s","-");
Regex.Replace(input, "^\w-","");
```

This will replace all whitespace characters by dashes and all non-word non-dash characters by the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

([A-Za-z0-9 ]*) This regex will simply allow you to get only letters,  numers and spaces. 
Then you can easily append every result to string

I dont know too much C# but in Python I would use simple replacement.

```
text = "tony's auto shop 123 main st."
s=""
res = re.findall("([A-Za-z0-9 ]*)",text)
for word in res:
    s=s+word
print s(prints tonys auto shop 123 main st)
```

if you need to replace all spaces for dash just repl it 
text = re.sub("","-",s)

Answer (score 0):

```
  string input = "tony's auto shop 123 main st.";

  //Gets rid of spaces and replaces with '-'
  string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+-?\s*", "-");

  //Replaces all non-alphanumeric characters with "", with the exception of '-'
  result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, "[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]", "");

  Console.WriteLine(result);
  Console.ReadLine();
```

I did this using a console app & regex.

The output is "tonys-auto-shop-123-main-st
"